# Difference between Vacuum permeability and Vacuum permittivity

Tags: electricity

I have read these articles: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_permittivity
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_permeability

I What I came up with is that

1. Vacuum permeability says "Two thin, straight, stationary, parallel wires, a distance $r$ apart in free space, each carrying a current $I$, will exert a force on each other. Ampère's force law states that the force per length $L$ is given by $\frac{F_m}{L}=\frac{\mu_o}{2\pi}\frac{I^2}{r}$.
2. Vacuum permittivity says "The experiments of Coulomb and others showed that the force $F$ between two equal point-like "amounts" of electricity, situated a distance $r$ apart in free space, should be given by a formula that has the form". $F_c=\frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_o}\frac{q_1q_2}{r^2}$.
3. From the definitions what I understand is that they are the same thing except permeability measures the force between wires per length, and permittivity measures the force between two point like charges.

Question:

1. Do they basically have the same meaning with the exception that permeability measures the force between wires per length, and permittivity measures the force between two point like charges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The permeability and permittivity of free space, $\mu_0$ and $\epsilon_0$, are **not the same**. This you can already see by their different units $F/m$ and $N/A^2$, respectively. However, in the SI system, they are related by the speed of light $c_0$ via $$\epsilon_0 \mu_0=\frac{1}{c_0^2}$$ The value of $\mu_0=4\pi 10^{-7}N/A^2$ is *assumed*. Thus the value of $\epsilon_0= 8.854187817620 10^{-12} F/m$ is given by the speed of light $c_0$.

Comment: My question is what is different in their meaning? They both seem to mean the force between electric charges with the exception that permeability measures the force between wires per length, and permittivity measures the force between two point like charges?

Comment: No, $\mu$ measures the force between *currents*, not charges.

Comment: @Arpad Szendrei - fqq is, of course, right. In one case it it the force between charges, in the other case it is the force between currents. If you stop the current in the wire, the charges do not change but the magnetic force is zero.

Comment: thank you. so μ is for flowing charge (current, which creates a magnetic field). And ϵ is for stationary charge (which does not create a magnetic field). So it makes sense, because μ is also determined by c (compared to ϵ) because the charge needs to flow for μ (and that speed c sets its propagation maximum).

Comment: @ArpadSzendrei - Yes, you are completely right!